# Stop capture element in windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone, runtime

How do I stop `camera element` when I do page navigate? I am using this

```
await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
```

but it is not working when I navigate back to my MainPage and I get this error

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the information you give us to see what's wrong in your code is helpless.When you get an unhandled exception check the inner 'e' param , usually you'll se what's wrong with your code.

Regardless , you could try to Dispose your MediaCapture object to prevent some access violation errors.Simply use

```
_mediaCapture.Dispose();
```

at 'OnNavigatedFrom' event of your page.